# nginx gunicorn with docker: how to use multiple dockerfiles

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I'm using the following [example](http://pawamoy.github.io/2018/02/01/docker-compose-django-postgres-nginx.html) to build a django-postgres-nginx-gunicorn web server. I'd like to have separated folders for each container. The following structure of the project works correctly. The main Dockerfile is used for the hello app (the django project):

```
svm3_03
|____Dockerfile
|____config
|    |____gunicorn
|    |    |____conf.py
|    |____nginx
|    |    |____conf.d
|    |         |____local.conf
|    |____db
|         |____db_env
|____docker
|    |__db
|       |__Dockerfile
|       |__dataForDB
|__docker-compose.yml
|__hello
```

the docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'
...
services:
   djangoapp:
      build:
         context: .
...
```

and the Dockerfile has the following line:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "config/gunicorn/conf.py", "--bind", ":8000", "--chdir", "hello", "hello.wsgi:application"]
```

Everything works. Now I tried to have the same structure as the DB image also for the django app so I move the main Dockerfile and the hello directory inside the docker folder... I created a new folder inside the docker folder with name djangoapp and I moved there the Dockerfile and the hello folder. The new structure is the following:

```
svm3_03
|____config
|    |____gunicorn
|    |    |____conf.py
|    |____nginx
|    |    |____conf.d
|    |         |____local.conf
|    |____db
|         |____db_env
|____docker
|    |__db
|    |  |__Dockerfile
|    |  |__dataForDB
|    |__djangoapp
|       |__Dockerfile
|       |__hello
|__docker-compose.yml
```

All I did then was to change the context line in the docker-compose.yml file like this:

```
version: '3'
...
services:
   djangoapp:
      build:
         context: ./docker/djangoapp
...
```

Now I get the following error:

```
djangoapp_1_7b3c77a4b939 | Error: can't chdir to 'hello'...
```

which is due to gunicorn and the command line CMD inside the djangoapp Dockerfile. Clearly changing the context in docker-compose.yml is not enough... any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Here is the full dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/djangoapp/src

WORKDIR /opt/services/djangoapp/src

COPY . /opt/services/djangoapp/src
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r hello/requirements.txt
RUN cd hello && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "config/gunicorn/conf.py", "--bind", ":8000", "--chdir", "hello", "hello.wsgi:application"]
```

Comment: better to post your dockerfile here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to track the problem. My error was in the Dockerfile of the django app. The command to run gunicorn has to point to the right directory. Here is the correct command:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "config/gunicorn/conf.py", "--bind", ":8000", "--chdir", "docker/djangoapp/hello", "hello.wsgi:application"]
```

Note the argument of the --chdir option.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with `/hello` but with `config/`, it doesn't appear that it has been copied inside the container. To verify, `exec -it` into the container and `ls`.

You need to pass that folder inside, one solution is to use volume:

services:
   djangoapp:
      volume:
      - ./config:/opt/services/djangoapp/src

Another solution is to copy it in the image, you will need to change your build context or docker will complain about copying file from outside the context

```
services:
   djangoapp:
      build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: ./docker/djangoapp/Dockerfile
```

and change paths in your Dockerfile to be relative to the new context

```
COPY ./docker/djangoapp /opt/services/djangoapp/src
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment... however it looks like it doesn't solve the problem. I tried both your suggestions but the problem is still there. I also copied the full config folder within docker/djangoapp and with "docker run -it svm3_03_djangoapp /bin/bash" I checker its existence in the container... in fact it was there but the problem persisted...

Comment: are you sure your `config/` and `hello/` are at the same level? the latter is in `src/`